# FULLTEXT not returning some searched words

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I'm using fulltext in my search bar on my website. The code looks like this,

search.php

```
<form method="post" action="search.php">
<input type="text" name="search" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
<?php
include("config.php");
$search = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search']);
echo $search;
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM shop
    WHERE MATCH (name,description,keywords) AGAINST ('$search' IN BOOLEAN MODE);") or die(mysql_error());
while ($info = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)) {
    $name = stripslashes($info['name']);
    $desc = stripslashes($info['description']);
    Print "<h3><a href=\"result.php?product=".urlencode($name)."\">".$name."</a>: <font color=\"#cd0000\">".$desc."</font></h3><br>";
}
?>
```

And this works completely fine...for the most part.  In my database, one of the rows under the description column reads: "1. Never run mysqld as root"

When I search "Never" or "Never run" into the search bar (without quotes obviously) This result does not show up.  However, if I search "Never run mysqld" or just "mysqld" then this result shows up.  Any idea why not all the words trigger the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- ['never' is in the fulltext stopword list](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-stopwords.html)
- ['run' is less then the default `ft_min_word_len=4` characters](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len)